# Does a larger bond energy in reactants mean a more exothermic reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, bond, energy

In the book "Combustion Physics" for C.K Law, page 42, it is stated that:

> The parameter that has the next strongest influence on [adiabatic flame temperature] $T_{ad}$ is the $C/H$ ratio of the fuel molecule, with $T_{ad}$ increasing with increasing $C/H$ ratio. There are three factors that need to be considered to explain such a behavior. First, species with large $C/H$ ratios often contain more double and triple $C-C$ bonds, which can hold more potential energy than the single bond. For example, we have shown that the enthalpy of the reaction $C_2H_6 → C_2H_4 + H_2$ is endothermic by $32.7$ kcal/mol. Since the enthalpy of formation of $H_2$ is zero, one can then conclude that ethylene stores more energy than ethane and thereby contributes to the higher $T_{ad}$ for ethylene.

It is implied from the above that a large bond energy for the reactants means there is more energy to be liberated by combustion. However, my understanding is that we need to **give** energy to the reactants in order to break their bonds, and energy is then liberated by the formation of bonds in the products. Thus a large bond energy for the reactants would mean a more endothermic reaction. Is my view point correct? If so then what does the author mean exactly?

Comment: You are correct. The interpretation and wording depends on the point of view.  It is like jumping from a shallow hole to a deep hole. One POV evaluates the absolute hole deepness with the all potential energy negative. Another POV evaluates their relative deepness, taking as the reference not the flat surface above, but the target depth of the deeper hole.

Comment: @Poutnik but this still doesn't explain why contradiction in the deductions. Would the reaction become more exothermic or endothermic when reactants have higher bonding energy?

Comment: It does. It depends what is meant by higher bonding energy as it is an unclear term. Higher energy because of weak bonding ( leads to exothermic reaction ), or higher energy released by existing bond formation ( leads to endothermic reaction)  ?

Comment: @Poutnik Hmm, my understanding is that double and triple bonds are stronger than a single bond and require more energy to break.

Comment: $\ce{C#C}$ is very strong bond, but $\ce{C2H2}$ is an endothermic compound and pressurerized can explosively form carbon and hydrogen. ( that is why it is stored in pressurized cylinders dissolved in acetone ).

Comment: All this is just semantic

Comment: I would not excuse this away by saying it's semantic or simply POV-dependent.  What Law wrote is completely wrong-headed, and shows a fundamental lack of understaning of the details of chemistry.  He writes "double and triple − bonds...hold more potential energy than the single bond", cleary indicating he thinks double/triple bonds have higher PE than single bonds.  No, they have lower PE.   The reason ethylene has higher E than ethane isn't because the C=C double bond is higher in PE than a C-C single bond. Instead, it's because, the presence of the C=C bond in place of a C-C bond means..

Comment: you have fewer bonds total.  *That's what gives you the higher energy.*  I.e., the higher energy of the ethene is *in spite of* the *lower* PE of the C=C bond, not becaue of a fallacious higher PE of that bond.  Specifically, in going from ethene to ethane, you are going from one C=C + four C-H + one H-H (6 bonds), to one C-C plus six C-H (7 bonds).  And the former has higher energy than the latter.  That's because, while the C-H and H-H bonds have about the same PE, and C=C has a lower PE than C-C, the *combined* PE of one C-C + one C-H bond is lower (more negative) than that of C=C.